# Gazebo JointController only responding intermittently

Tags: gz-sim

I have the following (relatively) simple sdf.  Some of the numbers are wierd because this was generated from a urdf, but gazebo should only be seeing the sdf content here.

```
<sdf version='1.10'>
  <model name='Simple'>
    <link name='base_link'>
      <inertial>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <mass>0.0090000000000000011</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.0030000000000000001</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.0030000000000000001</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>0.0030000000000000001</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
      <collision name='base_link_fixed_joint_lump__collision_collision'>
        <pose>0 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <length>1</length>
            <radius>3</radius>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual name='base_link_fixed_joint_lump__visual_visual'>
        <pose>0 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <length>1</length>
            <radius>3</radius>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <diffuse>0 0 0 1</diffuse>
          <ambient>0 0 0 1</ambient>
        </material>
      </visual>
    </link>
    <joint name='bottom_joint' type='revolute'>
      <pose relative_to='base_link'>0 0 1.1000000000000001 0 0 0</pose>
      <parent>base_link</parent>
      <child>bottom_arm</child>
      <axis>
        <xyz>1 0 0</xyz>
        <limit>
          <lower>-2.5</lower>
          <upper>2.5</upper>
          <effort>10</effort>
          <velocity>10</velocity>
        </limit>
        <dynamics>
          <damping>0.5</damping>
          <friction>0</friction>
          <spring_reference>0</spring_reference>
          <spring_stiffness>0</spring_stiffness>
        </dynamics>
      </axis>
    </joint>
    <link name='bottom_arm'>
      <pose relative_to='bottom_joint'>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <inertial>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <mass>0.0080000000000000002</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.002</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.002</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>0.002</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
      <collision name='bottom_arm_fixed_joint_lump__collision_collision'>
        <pose>0 0 0.050000000000000003 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <length>0.10000000000000001</length>
            <radius>0.5</radius>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual name='bottom_arm_fixed_joint_lump__arm_visual'>
        <pose>0 0 2.5 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <length>5</length>
            <radius>0.5</radius>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <diffuse>0 0 1 1</diffuse>
          <ambient>0 0 1 1</ambient>
        </material>
      </visual>
    </link>
    <plugin name='gz::sim::systems::JointController' filename='gz-sim-joint-controller-system'>
      <topic>move_bottom_joint</topic>
      <joint_name>bottom_joint</joint_name>
    </plugin>
    <frame name='base_link_joint' attached_to='base_link'>
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    </frame>
    <frame name='base' attached_to='base_link_joint'>
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    </frame>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

I start Gazebo (7.0.0) with the empty world and spawn my urdf using the create service.

Everything looks like I expect, but when I publish the gazebo topic for the JointController:

`gz topic -t /move_bottom_joint -m gz.msgs.Double -p "data: 0.5"`

nothing happens.  I hit the up arrow and re-submit the exact same command several times, and eventually the joint starts to move.  Then I try to publish "data: 0.0" to get it to stop, and again nothing happens until the third, eightth, or twentieth time.  It varies, and seems random.

To recap, my joint controller seems to only sporadically respond to the messages it is supposed to be subscribed to.  Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

EDIT to add additional information:
I didn't think this was relevant, but I don't know what it and isn't at this point.

I'm running on a VMWare virtual machine running Ubuntu Jammy 22.04.3, and I noticed that when I run `gz sim` I get the following in the terminal:

```
VMware: No 3D enabled (0, Success).
libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
VMware: No 3D enabled (0, Success).
libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
```

This appears to be related to the GUI while my problem seems to be in the server, but I'm thinking anything is possible...  Surely I'm not the first person to run Gazebo in a virtual machine.  Maybe my setup there is faulty?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine when I run it.
I am running Gazebo Sim Garden 7.5.0 built from source.

Try to run `gz sim world.sdf` with following `world.sdf` file, to rule out e.g. loading the correct physics plugin:

````
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sdf version="1.9">
  <world name="test">
    <scene>
      <ambient>1 1 1</ambient>
      <grid>false</grid>
    </scene>

        <physics name="4ms" type="ignored">
            <max_step_size>0.004</max_step_size>
            <real_time_factor>1.0</real_time_factor>
        </physics>


  <model name='Simple'>
    <link name='base_link'>

      <inertial>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <mass>0.0090000000000000011</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.0030000000000000001</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.0030000000000000001</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>0.0030000000000000001</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>

      <collision name='base_link_fixed_joint_lump__collision_collision'>
        <pose>0 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <length>1</length>
            <radius>3</radius>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </collision>

      <visual name='base_link_fixed_joint_lump__visual_visual'>
        <pose>0 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <length>1</length>
            <radius>3</radius>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <diffuse>0 0 0 1</diffuse>
          <ambient>0 0 0 1</ambient>
        </material>
      </visual>
    </link>

    <joint name='bottom_joint' type='revolute'>
      <pose relative_to='base_link'>0 0 1.1000000000000001 0 0 0</pose>
      <parent>base_link</parent>
      <child>bottom_arm</child>
      <axis>
        <xyz>1 0 0</xyz>
        <limit>
          <lower>-2.5</lower>
          <upper>2.5</upper>
          <effort>10</effort>
          <velocity>10</velocity>
        </limit>
        <dynamics>
          <damping>0.5</damping>
          <friction>0</friction>
          <spring_reference>0</spring_reference>
          <spring_stiffness>0</spring_stiffness>
        </dynamics>
      </axis>
    </joint>
    <link name='bottom_arm'>
      <pose relative_to='bottom_joint'>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <inertial>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <mass>0.0080000000000000002</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.002</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.002</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>0.002</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
      <collision name='bottom_arm_fixed_joint_lump__collision_collision'>
        <pose>0 0 0.050000000000000003 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <length>0.10000000000000001</length>
            <radius>0.5</radius>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual name='bottom_arm_fixed_joint_lump__arm_visual'>
        <pose>0 0 2.5 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <length>5</length>
            <radius>0.5</radius>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <diffuse>0 0 1 1</diffuse>
          <ambient>0 0 1 1</ambient>
        </material>
      </visual>
    </link>
    <plugin name='gz::sim::systems::JointController' filename='gz-sim-joint-controller-system'>
      <topic>move_bottom_joint</topic>
      <joint_name>bottom_joint</joint_name>
    </plugin>
    <frame name='base_link_joint' attached_to='base_link'>
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    </frame>
    <frame name='base' attached_to='base_link_joint'>
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    </frame>
  </model>


    <model name="ground_plane">
        <static>true</static>
        <link name="link">
            <collision name="collision">
                <geometry>
                    <plane>
                        <normal>0 0 1</normal>
                        <size>100 100</size>
                    </plane>
                </geometry>
                <surface>
                    <friction>
                        <ode>
                            <mu>100</mu>
                            <mu2>50</mu2>
                        </ode>
                    </friction>
                </surface>
            </collision>
        </link>
    </model>

    <plugin filename="gz-sim-physics-system"
            name="gz::sim::systems::Physics">
    </plugin>
    <plugin filename="gz-sim-scene-broadcaster-system"
            name="gz::sim::systems::SceneBroadcaster">
    </plugin>

  </world>
</sdf>
```
````

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I tried your sdf and got the same result.  I also edited my question with additional information.

Comment: Try and run the example demo worlds. I don't know if they are installed by default or if it's a separate package, but otherwise you can also find them [here](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/tree/gz-sim7/examples/worlds).

Comment: I ran the diff_drive.sdf demo world.  The header of that file gives example commands, so I copy-pasted one of those to my command line.  Same result: I had to submit it several times and eventually the car started moving.  :-(